# How to eliminate excessive vertical space after \cmidrule in table

Tags: tables, spacing

How can I eliminate the excessive vertical space that occurs after a row where I use the \cmidrule command?

[image: LaTex table with excessive vertical space after \cmidrule]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Conditions} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Friedman} \\
         \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-8} \\
         & \textbf{N} & \textbf{M} & \textbf{A} & N & $\chi^2$ & DF & \textbf{Sig.} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Text 8} & .04 & .28 & .04 & 12 & 1.4 & 2 & 0.497 \\
        \textbf{Text 13} & .04 & .08 & .12 & 12 & 3.8 & 2 & 0.147 \\
        \textbf{Text 14} & \textcolor{red}{-.12} & .12 & .12 & 12 & 3.4 & 2 & 0.187 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Mean Standardized Effort Rankings per Condition/Text and Friedman Test Results}
    \label{tab:meanEffort_perTextTask}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I tried using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} % Default value: 1` before the table to get it to snug up the row, but it alters all rows (and it didn't work to set arraystretch right before the row in my table with the \cmidrule commands and then right after to reset it to defaults):

[image: LaTex table with excessive vertical space after \cmidrule after trying \arraystretch command]

How can I change the spacing of only the row with the \cmidrule commands?

Comment: Use only  `\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-8}` (remove the  the double backlash)

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Simon Dispa said, all I needed to do was remove the double backslash from the line where I use the \cmidrule commands:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Conditions} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Friedman} \\
         \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-8}
         & \textbf{N} & \textbf{M} & \textbf{A} & N & $\chi^2$ & DF & \textbf{Sig.} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Text 8} & .04 & .28 & .04 & 12 & 1.4 & 2 & 0.497 \\
        \textbf{Text 13} & .04 & .08 & .12 & 12 & 3.8 & 2 & 0.147 \\
        \textbf{Text 14} & \textcolor{red}{-.12} & .12 & .12 & 12 & 3.4 & 2 & 0.187 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Mean Standardized Effort Rankings per Condition/Text and Friedman Test Results}
    \label{tab:meanEffort_perTextTask}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table using \cmidrule commands with excessive vertical space issue resolved]